# Return Generic type T in a Method

Tags: java, generics, types, casting

the following class simulates a generic matrix which can be filled with Ts, where .

```
public class GenMatrix<T extends Number> {
//local matrix 
T[][] matrix;

public GenMatrix(T[][] matrix) {
    //if matrix is n x n, set it as local
    if (matrix.length == matrix[0].length)
        this.matrix = matrix;
}

//multiplies the matrix with a vector of the same type T and returns a Double vector
Double[] multVector (T[] vector){

    //check wether the matrix can be multiplied with the vector
    if (vector.length != matrix.length) return null;

    //new Double vector
    Double[] result = new Double[matrix.length];

    //matrix - vector -multiplication
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
            //cast all Ts into Doubles
            result[j] += ((Double)matrix[i][j])*((Double)vector[j]);
        }
    }
    return result;  
}
```

}

As you can see the method multVector(..) returns a Double[].
My question: Why can't it return a T[]? If i dont cast the matrix and vector entries in the calculation to Double, the compiler says " the operator "*" is unknown for the type T". Im wondering about that since T extends Number and Number is a calculatable (isnt it?).
I am not searching for a workaround to return a T[] Vector but for the answere of the "why doesnt it work"-question.

Regards Tak3r07

Comment: `*` is a special operator for certain kinds of primitive data types. If you want to be able to multiply the numbers contained in your class, you have to restrict `T` to a class with a method similar to `multiply`.

Answer (score 0):

When something extends `Number`, you can't necessarily cast it into a `Double`, `Integer` or any other child class. Read about the difference between primitive and Object datatypes in Java. The numeric operators only work on the primitive types. What happens when you apply your cast to `Double` and use the `*`, Java will perform a process called **auto-unboxing**.

Your casts can run into `ClasscastException`s. Instead of this

```
result[j] += ((Double)matrix[i][j])*((Double)vector[j]);
```

do this:

```
result[j] += (matrix[i][j].doubleValue())*(vector[j].doubleValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathematical operators are not defined for `Number`. They are defined for numeric primitives: `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`. The reason that you can say:

```
Integer i = 5;
int j = i +  2;
```

is *autoboxing* that automatically replaces `i` by `i.intValue()` in expression `i + 2`.

This is the reason that you cannot use `+` operator with generic type `T`.

Method `multVector()` can return generic type: T[] multVector(T[] input)`. To do this you should pass your definition of`*` to the method:

```
interface MathOperator<T> {
    perform(T one, T two);
} 

class MultiplyDouble  implements MathOperator<Double> {
    perform(Double one, Double two) {
        return one * two;
    }
}


T[] multVector (T[] vector, MathOperator<T> operator){...}
```

Now you can call this method as following:

```
multVector (new Double[] {1.1, 2.2, 3.3}, new MultiplyDouble());
```

BTW creating instance of generic array is challenge too. TIP: user class `java.lang.reflect.Array`.

Answer (score 0):

`multVector`could of course return  an array of T. The problems are :

- you cannot do operations on a type-variable, nor on `Number` class
- you cannot create an array of type-variable

For the first part, you must know the actual class represented by T. So you should have :

```
...
T[][] matrix;
Class<T> clazz;

public GenMatrix(T[][] matrix, Class<T> clazz) {
    //if matrix is n x n, set it as local
    if (matrix.length == matrix[0].length)
        this.matrix = matrix;
        this.clazz = clazz;
}
...
    T[] result = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, matrix.length);
...
```

For the second, you could keep on making calculations on double and casting at the end:

```
abstract <T> fromDouble(double value); // to be implemented in actual class

    //matrix - vector -multiplication
    double res;
    for (int j = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        res = 0.;
        for (int i = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
            //cast all Ts into Doubles
            res += matrix[i][j].doubleValue() * vector[j].doubleValue();
        }
        resul[j] = fromDouble(res);
    }
```

As you see, it is far more complicated for a limited gain.